# How do I get back to the app from Google Maps?

Tags: android, react-native, google-maps, maps, background-process

My app is made on React Native (Android only). When I click the button, the Google Maps app opens. Is there any way to implement a return to my app from Google Maps other than opening the entire list of apps open right now.

There is an idea to implement the app icon in the StatusBar when opening another app for a quick go back.

Do you have any other ideas ?

Comment: The user can just tap the device back button, and it will take them back to your app.

Comment: Also you can try to use the google maps service in your app and open the map in a modal or a stack screen.

Comment: You could also use the Google Maps intents for Android: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents